# Open pfx certificate container in .NET

Tags: .net, pfx

Where can I find information on opening a PFX store which contains a certificate? I came across [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms867088.aspx), however I am kind of loast at the PfxOpen Class.

Edit - I have a pfx file exported with a private key. I am storing that in my database. I want to be able to open the pfx file and read information from the certificate contained in that pfx file, example the serial, expiration date etc.

Comment: Please explain what exactly you need to do, this will affect the answer. "open a store" is a way to do .. what?

Comment: Can someone kindly remove the down-vote, please!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(filename, password)

from there you can see what's in the cert. the X509Certificate2 has many overloads. check it out.